# How to get the first object after filtering an array in jq?

Tags: json, select, jq

Given the following JSON

```
{
  "tags": [
    {
      "key": "env",
      "value": "foo"
    },
     {
      "key": "env",
      "value": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to find out the first tag where the key is `env`. I have this-

```
.tags[] | select (.key=="env") |.[0]
```

but that gives me an error `Cannot index object with number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `first(expr)` to provide an expression that satisfies your usecase.

```
first(.tags[]? | select(.key == "env") .value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the results of your query in an array and then pick the first one

```
[.tags[] | select(.key=="env")] | .[0]
```

Comment: is there a more readable/alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

```sh
jq -r 'first( .tags[] | select(.key=="env") ).value'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/UphoXETxo-)

---

`.tags[]` flattens the array into a stream of values. You're applying `.[0]` to each of the values, not a filtered array. To filter an array, you'd use

```
.tags | map(select(...)) | .[0]
```

or

```
.tags | map(select(...)) | first
```

`map(...)` is a shorthand for `[ .[] | ... ]`, so the above is equivalent to

```
.tags | [ .[] | select(...) ] | first
```

and

```
[ .tags[] | select(...) ] | first
```

Finally, `[ ... ] | first` can be written as `first(...)`.

```
first( .tags[] | select(...) )
```